# Clean Windows UAC Registration of App

Tags: windows-7, uac

I created an application that had a signed assembly manifest to run as administrator, but I need the application to be moved back down to a user application.  However, even after removing the assembly manifest Windows 7 still sees the app as an elevated app.  It appears to be tied to the name, because if I change the name the app then no longer requires admin privileges.

Does the OS have some special cache that needs to be cleared?  If so, how do I locate my application in that cache and clean it out manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows will guess based on things like filename and version info if no manifest is present, so you should still use a manifest, just request as-invoker privileges.